# Git rebasing attribute the change to the wrong file

Tags: git, git-rebase

I think I found a bug in git, where a change gets attributed to the wrong file when doing a rebasing, is there any known workaround ?

## Short summary

Assume `master_branch`

```
.
└── parent_folder
    ├── project_a
    │   └── file.txt 
    └── project_b
        └── file.txt # the 2 file.txt have the same content on master
```

Assume `feature_branch` from master

```
.
└── parent_folder
    ├── project_a
    │   └── file.txt
    └── project_b
        └── file.txt # this file got modified with a feature
```

Assume `refactor_branch` from master

```
.
└── refactored_parent_folder # got renamed
    ├── project_a
    │   └── file.txt
    └── project_b
        └── file.txt
```

then rebase `feature_branch` on `refactor_branch`,

```
.
└── refactored_parent_folder 
    ├── project_a
    │   └── file.txt # the feature got moved here !
    └── project_b
        └── file.txt # instead of here, where it should be !
```

## Reproduction bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# tested on linux, git version 2.34.1, 2.43.2.

set -ex
# create a master branch
mkdir -p git_repo
cd git_repo
git init
mkdir -p parent_folder/project_a
echo -e "1\n2\n3" > parent_folder/project_a/file.txt
cp -r parent_folder/project_a parent_folder/project_b
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
# we create a feature_branch from master
git branch "feature_branch"

# we create a refactoring_branch from master
git checkout -b "refactoring_branch"

git mv parent_folder refactored_parent_folder
git add .
git commit -m "refactor"

# we create a new feature in project_b
git checkout "feature_branch"
echo -e "1\n2_some_new_feature_in_project_b\n3" > parent_folder/project_b/file.txt
git add .
git commit -m "new feature"

# we rebase 
git rebase refactoring_branch
cat refactored_parent_folder/project_a/file.txt
# refactored_parent_folder/project_a/file.txt contains the line 2_some_new_feature_in_project_I think I found a bug in gitb, which is WRONG ! 
# It should have ended  up in refactored_parent_folder/project_b/file.txt
```

## ENV

tested on linux, git version 2.34.1, 2.43.2 are affected

Comment: I do not see a bug there... but that's just _my_ opinion, right?. How would you propose it should work? What is your expected outcome of that flow?

Comment: I edited the post to make that more obvious. feature in `project_b` should STAY in `project_b`, not suddenly move to `project_a`

Comment: Oh... but way, the files have _the same_ content when you start?

Comment: Yes, I edited the summary to make it obvious, you can read the reproduction script for more details

Comment: It's ok.... I understand..... yes, this sounds like a little improvement could be written there in git.

Comment: I’m convinced. You can report to git@vger.kernel.org

Comment: Git does not keep track of renames. It tries to guess them based on the file content. It guesses successfully most of the times, even when the content of the renamed file changes, less than some threshold. Since you started with two identical files and their paths do not matter, the fact that it mismatched them is an unfortunate mistake but it is between the limits of its specs. With other words, this is how Git works. Of course, nothing prevents you to report it as a bug to the Git maintainers. They improve the product all the time, maybe in the future they add support for file renames.

Comment: thanks, I just did report it to the dev

Comment: “Git does not keep track of renames. It tries to guess them based on the file content.”—That seems academic in this context. It had three choices: (1) error out (dunno what to do?), (2) use the file with a different basename, or (3) choose the file with the same basename. Given that the two files have identical content, it chose (2), the least reasonable option.

Comment: @axiac But [Elijah Newren](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CABPp-BGi6m3SLce8TbZJOMuu610o0PEf+NgaqqfTzZHrqcYzFA@mail.gmail.com/T/#m6203cc111bc0c95c73619d32f0ec2eca79adb79b) from the mailing list agrees with you (picking an arbitrary file is fine)

Comment: @Guildenstern Git stores only one copy of the content of the identical files. The same content can be reached through multiple paths. The path and the content are not stored together; the path refers the content but not the other way around. Any strategy to choose one path or another is arbitrary.

Comment: @axiac Storing one copy (blob) doesn’t seem relevant. It is well-known that renames aren’t stored. The contention is that the rename heuristic is lacking. (It could also just fail: `fatal: confusing renaming!`, like I said.) I’ll ask whether this is documented in git-rebase(1) since I didn’t find anything in a jiffy. Cheers.

Comment: It is relevant because, in order to detect the renames, Git compares the contents. It finds the old content, it finds one of its names and it does not care if there are other names for the same content. It does not have any reason to care. Storing the content only once is an implementation detail, not a contract. In order to fulfill the request of the OP, Git should try to identify all renames at once, to sort the potential source and target paths and to try to match them. A goal not easy to accomplish, if it is even possible, and too much work for a case that does not happen often enough.